# Problem with HTML frameset and frame

Tags: php, web-services, html

I am using the below HTML file. The page displays nothing and my text editor is highlighting the `frameset` tags in yellow color showing it is an error (or warning). What is wrong with this code?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <frameset>
            <frame src="http://google.com/" scrolling="yes">
        </frameset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<body>` tag. Also the closing tag `</body>`

```
<html>
    <head></head>

        <frameset>
            <frame src="http://google.com/" scrolling="yes">
        </frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: That's indeed one of the issues. The other issues is that FF will simply re-direct to google.com and, well, framset, really??!!

Comment: @AR Apparently he is using frameset ;) Is strange that your FF redirects to google.com. Just tested in Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari and IE9 and they all display in the address bar the local html file address.

Comment: It is strange to have a frameset consisting of just one frame.

Answer (score 0):

I believe  needs a width attribute:

```
<frameset cols="*">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove body and add a cols or rows attribute to the frameset.  Also, reference the Frameset DTD, which will give you the rules for using frames.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://google.com/" scrolling="yes"/>
    </body>
</html>
```